# How to appear in the right column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem which is the data did not appear in the column. Only the first data. Name data should appear at column B9.

And fyi, name will appear at column A in last data.

The data will come out like this;

[image]

Where should I need to fix my error?

And the error I think is at this line -

```
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 1) = txtName.Text
```

Hope anyone of you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data")
Dim Addme As Range, str As String, totalRows As Long

Set Addme = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Me.txtName = "" Or Me.cboAmount = "" Or Me.cboCeti = "" Then
    MsgBox "There is insufficient data, Please return and add the needed information"
    Exit Sub
End If

totalRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
totalRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(totalRows, 3)

ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 1) = txtName.Text

If cbWhatsapp.Value = True Then
    str = "Whatsapp, "
End If

If cbSMS.Value = True Then
    str = str & "SMS, "
End If

If cbEmail.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Email, "
End If

If cbFacebook.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Facebook, "
End If

If cbPhoneCall.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Phone Call, "
End If
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 2) = str

If optYes.Value = True Then
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 3) = "Yes"
ElseIf optNo.Value = True Then
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 3) = "No"
End If

ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 4) = cboAmount.Value
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 5) = cboCeti.Value
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 6) = txtPhone.Text
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 7) = txtEmail.Text

ws.Range("B9:H10000").Sort Key1:=Range("F9"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

MsgBox "Your data was successfully added"

Sheet1.Select

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value `totalRows` when your code runs?  Your screenshot has no row or column headers, so it's difficult to see what's wrong.

Comment: @TimWilliams hi i already edit the question.

Comment: `ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 1) = txtName.Text` puts the name in ColA - if it should be in ColB then change that to `ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 2) = txtName.Text`

Comment: it seems you have to shift ALL your columns index by one to the left

Comment: @DisplayName i alr got the answer. thanks btw :)